# How bad is doing a back-to-back connection to do VLAN mapping (vlan-stacking limitation)?

Tags: switch, switching

the object sounds like a newbie questions but there are good reason for it in the context of bridge-domains and vlan-stacking.
Here below a picture to give a bit of context

[image: Switch with VLAN mapping through back-to-back cable]

In short I realized that on the Huawei S5700 family for VLANs linked to bridge-domain I cannot use vlan-stacking.
The goal is to have tagged and untagged frames entering from the physical ports being properly marked stacked and then incapsulated into VxLAN.
Hence the idea to define two VLANs, one (4063) dedicated for vlan-stacking and the other one (4064 ) to be linked to the bridge-domain and the link between them esternal.

Is that bad? And how much?

Alex

Comment: Maybe, might I use vlan bridging?

Comment: You are talking about QinQ? Separate S and C tags?

Comment: Yes, on the (five) ingress ports I must stack untagged packets and assign them both a C-tag and S-tag (being the 4063)

Comment: That seems fine if the equipment supports Q-in-Q VLAN tagging. I don't see why you need the additional physical link between 4063 and 4064 unless that is how the physical network design works. You can implement Q-in-Q VLAN tagging in the software configuration. Huawei provides examples here: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000178168/bcc328a0/configuration-examples-for-qinq

Comment: The context is a bit different. Whenever a VLAN is linked to a BD, then selective QinQ doesn't work on that VLAN, therefore I thought to split the VLAN in two, one associated with the BD and one where I apply selective QinQ, then I just need to bridge the two. I tried to bridge the two VLANs internally but that's possible only in devices like routers, not switches.